# Android Java download manager no longer works

Tags: java, android-studio, android-download-manager

My code don't work anymore, because the Download manager don't accept the download link, but last Week the Download manager accept the link.
Can someone helps me? I think Google change something...
Thanks

change the link to someone other url(works)

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse("http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&q=" + searchTo.getText().toString()));
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/open_serach_data/cache", "suggest.txt");
DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

Comment: This code did not work due to a bug in Android. The Code is fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Android 9.0 Its Changing You should use

```
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse( url ));

        request.setDescription(title);
        request.setTitle(title);


        request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(f));

        img_d_id = manager.enqueue(request);
```